# AWS s3: How to unzip and read line by line from csv(in gz) file from aws s3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I tried to unzip and read file by using stream and then pipe it
But due to its async nature I am not able to handle it properly.

Below my code. Please help me

```
params = {
                Bucket: BucketName,
                Key: keyFileName                };

            } 
            s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(zlib.createGunzip());
```

Now how can I read the stream line by line from the file by a synchronize way

Comment: https://multiaki.medium.com/unzipping-s3-files-back-to-s3-without-uncompressing-entire-file-streaming-82f662b5065a

There are problems when trying  unzip as http stream
Maybe this article would help. Just skip the streaming back to S3 part